# Issue with CSV export in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system

As i am new to **Drupal 7** , i just wanted some feedback on how to debug the error in drupal 7

The work scenario will be,like this.

Once i have login into drupal 7 account i get these sub menus

> Add Content
>
> Find Content
>
> Class Admin
>
> Class Export

Now when i click on **Class Export** it will display a Grid with some data's and below the grid there is a *CSV* button which downloads a *CSV* format of the grid.

Till this its working fine and good.

Now the next step, In the top right side there is a edit view button which will help ne to edit / add the fields for the grid

Inside the edit view The page looks like this which is working fine
[image: Image 1]

Now as you can see in the image on the left side there is a Fields section where one can **add** / remove the fields.

Next step i will be adding some new fields

When i click on **ADD** i will get the below screen, and i will select the **Content : Class is certified**

> (Appears in : node : training_class)

[image: Image 2]

I will do apply (this display) and then save it.

Now when i click on CSV button i am not able to get the file , the page is not responding.

So i got to know that when i add a field Content :

> Class is certified (Appears in : node : training_class)

throws an error, But how to debug this issue?

How to find the issue in the drupal backend code base. How to find the root cause?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Views is a huge factory , so i use to exclude this module from my development. So i suggest to use another contrib module to make csv export or develop your own . But , if you really want to debug views issues you can check several avalaible hooks provided by views module https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7.x-3.x  AND checks your php logs too !

Comment: As first step, check on Reports -> Recent log messages (from admin menu). Drupal is logging all the messages (including errors) there.

Answer (score 0):

A bit detailed answer:

1. Check on Reports -> Recent log messages from admin menu.
2. Try editing php.ini file and enabling error messages, so when code crashes you'll be able to see error message.
3. From your browser (network tab) check what happens when you click icon for document download. Check what is the response from the server.
4. run phpinfo() command (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and check is logging of errors enabled and what is location of error log file. Check that file... phpinfo() will also show you location of loaded php.ini file.